# Apache error: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Tags: apache, symlink, ntfs-3g

I use Ubuntu as OS by default, but sometimes I need to use Windows 10 and would be convenient if I can have common access to all my web projects. I have two ssd for two OS. The first one only for Ubuntu (ext4 file system), the second one only for windows (ntfs file system). All projects store in the second one with ntfs file system (because in this case, I have access to the projects from windows and ubuntu).
In Windows, it works well. But for Ubuntu, I have an issue.

In Ubuntu, I created a symlink "/var/www/" to "/media/myuser/projects/www". With the real folder ("/var/www/"), it works good, but with symlink doesn't work.

Error log:

> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www

I know that for have access to symlinks need to edit apache configuration and add option "FollowSymLinks". I did it, but it still doesn't work.

Apache configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm sure that it ntfs mounting issue, because when I tried to add link "/var/www" to some ubuntu ext4 folder it worked.

Mounted devices with ntfs file system always have "0777" permissions, it means that issue doesn't relate to permissions.

```
$ ls -l /var/www
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 27 May 12 23:37 /var/www -> /media/myuser/projects/www/
```

Could you give me some advice with the apache ntfs mounting issue?

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 18.4. I can not see my link to the external SSD which is NTFS in apache. I can see the sym link to an directory on the same filesystem. How can it be fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You have to mount the NTFS SSD directly in `/etc/fstab` by a link to the /var/www. Then do `mount -a` . Then the SSD can be seen by apache in the Browser.